# Prove: if $x$ is even, then $x + 5$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, integers

I am trying to prove or disprove that if $x$ is even, then $x + 5$ is odd.

This is what I have thus far, but I am stuck:

- Assume that the chose variable (x) are in the domain:
  (x) is an integer
- Assume the IF part of the statement:
  (x) is even
- Prove the THEN part: 
  Let a be a dummy variable that we assume is an integer.
  $x=2a+1$ (Definition of an Odd Integer)

Now find $x+5$.

$x+5=2a+1+5$ (Because we added the same value to both sides of the equation)

$x+5=2a+6$

$x+5=2(a+3)$ (Because of the Distributive Property of Multiplication over Addition)

Let $z=a+3$;

$x + 5 = 2z,$ but this is the definition of an even integer; where did I mess up?

Comment: You're assuming that `x` is even, and therefore `x=2a+1` for some integer `a`? In other words, you've assumed that `x` is even, and also that `x` is odd...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general when faced with "even" or "odd" assumptions in proof for some variable $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, it's helpful to express $x$ in terms of some other integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

In your case, if $x$ is even, then there must exist some integer- we'll call it $k$- such that $x=2k$. We don't know exactly what value $k$ is, and frankly, we don't need to know.

Since $x=2k$, and we want to show that $x+5$ is odd, simply add 5 to the first value:

$$x+5= 2k+5$$
$$=2k+4+1$$
$$=2(k+2)+1$$

In general, we know that an odd number $m$ is one where for some integer $n$, $m=2n+1.$

Note that regardless of what $k$ is, $k+2$ will maintain its evenness or oddness (depending on $k$'s value); however, $2(k+2)$ will always be even.

And thus, $2(k+2)+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 5):

Your first line of proof does not agree with your assumption that x is even:

```
Assume the IF part of the statement: (x) is even
x=2a+1 (Definition of an Odd Integer)
```

Answer (score 4):

given $x$ is even so $x=2k$ where you took $x=2k+1$

Comment: `code`x = 2k
`code`2k + 5 = 2k + 6
`code`2k + 5 = 2(k+3)
`code`2k + 5 = 2r

Comment: $2k + 5 = 2k + 4 + 1 = 2(k +2) + 1$ which is odd.

Comment: where did the extra 1 come from?

Comment: I just broke it up: $5 = 4 + 1.$

Comment: @JoshuaMathews it isn't extra; 5=4+1

Answer (score 2):

Notice, since $x$ is even then it can be rewritten as $x=2m$

Where, $m$ is some integer

Now, we have $$x+5=2k+5=2k+4+1$$$$=2(k+2)+1=\color{blue}{2n+1}$$
Where, $n=k+2$ is an integer

Thus, we get $\color{red}{x+5}=\color{blue}{2n+1}$ which is an odd integer i.e. $\color{red}{x+5}$ is not even.

Comment: Thank you! I messed up from the very beginning.